# How to hide list or multi-line text behind anti-spoiler?

Tags: support, spoilers

[This comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114073/how-did-changelings-learn-who-killed-one-of-them?noredirect=1#comment292798_114073) (last parts) seems to be explaining everything:

> (...) it seems, that anti-spoiler can hide only one-line sentence. Breaking sentences into more than one line or trying to hide lists produces a very strange and not looking good effect.

Is it possible to use anti-spoiler tag (`>!`) to hide a list or block of text? Or what am I doing wrong?

I tried both with unordered list and with "converting" it into multi-line block of text, replacing "dots" with "a)", "b)", "c)" etc. All for nothing -- any attempt, that I undertook ended in converting multi-line block of text or list into single line (hidden behind anti-spoiler).

What am I missing?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396/262849

Comment: My guess is that you used a carriage return to move down to the next line, rather than using the correct markdown (a double-space at the end of the line).

Comment: Oh, please don't encourage people further to put their entire question into a spoiler block. This won't end well on the long run. You know why they work crap with paragraphs and structures? Because you ought to use them sparingly. ;-)

Comment: I struggled with similar formatting problems when I wrote http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/96701/4918

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You have to use HTML tags.**

I’m not quite sure why the regular Markdown formatting works in blockquotes but not in spoiler blocks; I dug into it a while back but never got very far with it. The limited subset of HTML supported by SE mostly just works in spoiler blocks.

Examples:

- For linebreaks, use `<br>`:

  ```
  >! This is a spoiler block <br> with multiple lines <br> of text
  ```

  > This is a spoiler block 
  >  with multiple lines 
  >  of text
- For paragraphs, use a double `<br>`:

  ```
  >! My first paragraph. <br><br> Another paragraph. Such words.
  ```

  > My first paragraph. 
  >  Another paragraph. Such words.

  I have used `<p>` and `</p>` tags in the past, although I have a vague recollection that it broke some spoiler markup on mobile.
- For lists, use `<ul>` and `<ol>`.

  ```
  >! My example list has
  >! <ol>
  >! <li>a first item</li>
  >! <li>and another item</li>
  >! <li>and a final item</li>
  >! </ol>
  ```

  > My example list has
  >
  > 1. a first item
  > 2. and another item
  > 3. and a final item

Answer (score 5):

@alexwlchan's answer gives one nice solution, but you don't necessarily *have* to use HTML tags for linebreaks and paragraphs. It's enough to **put two spaces at the end of each line**, like this:

```
>! one line  
>! another line  
>!  
>! after a blank line
```

which yields the following output:

> one line
>  another line
>
>  after a blank line

However, this doesn't work to give bulletpoints or list formatting within a spoiler block, for which see [Alex's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9191/31394).

---

On a related note, to get get *separate* spoiler blocks with nothing in between use either `<nbsp/>` or `<!-- --->` in between the two blocks.

```
>! one spoiler  

  <nbsp/>

>! another spoiler.
```

yields

> one spoiler

> another spoiler.